# UNIX replace particular line in file

Tags: file, unix, replace, command

I have file about 5.5GB of size. I want to view a particular line of the file. Lets say line number 100001 and I want to replace that line with my own texts. How to achieve this operation using Unix command. I can not view the file in editor. I can not be opened and that is a remote machine.

Can anyone share some idea to view that line and replacing it with some other texts?

Thanks :)

Comment: If it cannot be opened you have no hope, unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: If you know what that line is looking like, you could use `sed` to do find and replace on that line of the file.  But if the file cannot be opened, `sed` will not be of much use.

Comment: Probably cannot be opened because of the file size. Plus it's remote, so might just be accessing it via SSH.

Comment: How about this: sed -e "100001s/your-line/new-line/"  ?

Comment: @Ruel: yes you are right am accessing via SSH only. @Sujith: I will your command and let you know man. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the line in-place and the replacement data is the same length as the text being replaced, you can use `dd` to (carefully!) overwrite part of the file.

```
# getting the byte offsets of the start and length of the line
perl -ne '$s+=length; if ($.==100001) {print "$s + ",length,"\n"; exit}' bigfile

# writing over the existing data
echo 'new line' | dd of=bigfile bs=1 seek=$start count=$length conv=notrunc
```

If the replacement data is a different length, and it's not at the very end of the file, you have no choice but to rewrite the file.  This requires having enough disk space to keep both `bigfile` and a copy of it!

```
# The old file is renamed to bigfile.bak; a new bigfile is written with changes.
sed -i.bak -e '100001 c \
new line' bigfile
```